# Can we do constructor injection in service class in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

here is my Service class

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService @Inject constructor(private val repository : Repository) :
    FirebaseMessagingService() {....}

class Repository @Inject constructor(private val apiService: ApiService) {}
```

and ApiService is Interface

The problem is on the first launch of app. This app is crashing with below message

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.projects.driverapp.MyFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.projects.driverapp.MyFirebaseMessagingService> has no zero argument constructor
```

But after this crash, on second launch of app , this project works fine without crash,
what is the root cause ?

Comment: Can you try to move the variable from the constructor to a field and use `@Inject`? That can help you to narrow down the reason.

Comment: thanks feild injection is also there @Inject
    lateinit var repository: Repository

Comment: How are you providing repository/api service

Comment: by field injection as above mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **@AndroidEntryPoint** in your service class and Add field injection **(@Inject)**

**Example:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class YourServiceClass : Service() {

  @Inject lateinit var analyticsRepo: AnalyticsRepository // Replace your class
  ...
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes), it is recommended to annotate services with **@AndroidEntryPoint**. Typically, services should have a constructor with **zero parameters** so that they can be initiated using startService().

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes) say that services need to be annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`, and Services generally need a 0 parameter constructor, so they can be started with `startService()`.

Try annotating both your `ApiService` and `MyFirebaseMessagingService` classes with `@AndroidEntryPoint` and for `MyFirebaseMessagingService` try field injection only. Hope this helps